# Unsupported media file type

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

While using fetch web api for post request and passing some json data with hash and signature as a header parameter,every time while executing the code error seems to be unsupported file type but as against the error my header and body is proper, additionally my body parameter also not a file so I am confused whats wrong here.
Kindly look into this.

```
fetch('https://sboxapi.lazypay.in/api/lazypay/v2/payment/eligibility',{
                     method: 'post',
                     body : occFormatResponse,
                     header  :{
                         'signature' : hash,
                         'accessKey' : merchantAccessKey,
                         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                     }
                 })
                 .then(function(result){
                    console.log('result>>>>>>>',result);
                    // return result;
                 })
                 .catch(function(error){
                    console.log('error while  checking the eligibiliy>>>>>>',error);
                    // return error.response;
                 })
```

Below is the error

```
{"timestamp":1559713841465,"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","path":"/api/lazypay/v2/payment/eligibility","errorCode":"LP_GENERIC_ERROR","message":"Oops!! Something went wrong"}
```

Body parameter

```
        {   
                "userDetails" : {
                    "firstname" : "ravi",
                    "lastname" : "singh",
                    "mobile" : "9892197128",
                    "email" : "ravi.singh@adapty.com"
                },
                "amount" : {
                    "value" : 1000,
                    "currency" : "INR"
                },
                "address" : {
                    "address1" : "street1",
                    "address2" : "street2",
                    "city" : "pune",
                    "state" : "MH",
                    "country" : "IN",
                    "zip" : "411045"
                },
                "productSkuDetails" : {
                    "productId" : "10537492PK",
                    "description" : "test product",
                    "attributes" : {
                        "size" : "S",
                        "color" : "blue"
                    },
                    "imageUrl" : "www.google.com",
                    "shippable" : true,
                    "skuId" : "10537492",
                    "price" : 1000

                },
                "source" :  "fabindia",
                "customParams": {
                     "previousTransactionCount": "10",
                     "onboardingdate": "20-05-2009",
                     "usersignupdetails": "Google",
                     "IPaddress": "10.10.10.10"
                }
        }
```

Comment: can you add your body parameter, so may be it will help to solve

Comment: @SachinDane i have added the body parameter, do let me know if there is something